# finding the average amount for each combination occurence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (table1) :

```
| Country1 | Country2 |
  Canada      USA
  Canada      Mexico
  USA         Mexico
  USA         Canada
.
.
.
etc
```

Then I have another table (table2):

```
| Country | Date | Amount |
  Canada    01-01  1.00
  Canada    01-02  0.23
  USA       01-01  2.67
  USA       01-02  5.65
  USA       01-03  8.00
.
.
.
etc
```

I need a query which will combine the two tables into something like this:

```
| Country1 | Average_amount_when_combined_with_country2| Country2 | Average_amount_when_combined_with_country1 |
  Canada                       0.615                        USA                      4.16
  USA                          4.16                         Canada                   0.615
```

What is happening is when country 1 occurs with country 2  in the first table I would like to get the average amount for country 1 when country 2 is combined, and then vise versa as well, the average for country 2 when country 1 is combined.I tried different join techniques but can't quite get it work, but now I think I can't really do any traditional joins, I will need to use combinations of sub queries. I am completely stuck on how to get the average only when the two countries occur on the same date. This query is as close as I can get, but the problem is this just gets the average for the country as a whole, not for when the combination of two countries occurs.

```
select country1, (select avg(amount) from table2 where country = country1) ,country2,(select avg(amount) from table2 where country = country2)
from table1
```

Comment: Can you explain how you come up with 0.615 and 4.16?

Comment: What do you mean by "when country 2 is combined?" Combined how? Don't make us reverse-engineer your expected result, tell us exactly what you're doing, using precise terms.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Since Canada and USA together both occur on 01-01 and 01-02, I take the average for Canada on these two days ((1.00 + 0.23)/2) = 0.615 and do the same for the USA ((2.67+5.65)/2)=4.16

Comment: @AirThomas When I say combined I mean they occur together. For example, on the dates 01-01 and 01-02, CANADA and USA occur. Since Canada and USA together both occur on 01-01 and 01-02, I take the average for Canada on these two days ((1.00 + 0.23)/2) = 0.615 and do the same for the USA ((2.67+5.65)/2)=4.16. My goal is to see the average of amount of one country compared to the average amount of another country when they occurred on the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SELECT should solve your question, or at least should give you the idea how it works.

```
SELECT  t1.Country1, 
        t1.Country2, 
        (
            SELECT  AVG(Amount) 
            FROM    table2 t2 
            WHERE   t2.Country = t1.Country1 AND 
                    EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT 1      
                        FROM   table2 t3 
                        WHERE  t3.Country = t1.Country2 AND 
                               t2.Date = t3.Date
                    )
        ) Avg1, 
        (
            SELECT  AVG(Amount) 
            FROM    table2 t2 
            WHERE   t2.Country = t1.Country2 AND 
                    EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT 1      
                        FROM   table2 t3 
                        WHERE  t3.Country = t1.Country1 AND 
                               t2.Date = t3.Date
                    )
        ) Avg2
FROM table1 t1
```

See the result [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34968/3).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not sure if I am missing something, but table 1 does not have a date column, so I do not think I can make the join on this field.

Comment: I tried removing the date joins, but it shows the average for the entire country, instead of the average specific to the combination.

Comment: I corrected that and attached a sqlfiddle sample. Thanks to Brian for preparing that SQlFiddle

Answer (score 1):

This brings back the same information but in a more logical fashion, in my opinion (your expected output shows the same thing on both rows, just reversed).

```
select t2a.country as country1,
       t2b.country as country2,
       avg(t2b.amount) as avg_amount
  from table2 t2a
  join table2 t2b
    on t2a.date = t2b.date
  join table1 t1
    on t2a.country = t1.country1
   and t2b.country = t1.country2
 group by t2a.country, t2b.country
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34968/2/0

Output:

```
| COUNTRY1 | COUNTRY2 | AVG_AMOUNT |
|----------|----------|------------|
|   Canada |      USA |       4.16 |
|      USA |   Canada |      0.615 |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to aggregate `table2` by country before doing any joins.  Otherwise, you run the risk of a Cartesian product.  In MySQL, you would approach this with two subqueries:

```
select t1.country, t2_1.amount as avg1, t2.country, t2_2.amount
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.country, avg(amount) as amount
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.country
     ) t2_1
     on t1.country1 = t2_1.country join
     (select t2.country, avg(amount) as amount
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.country
     ) t2_2
     on t1.country2 = t2_2.country;
```

In other databases, you would probably use a common table expression (CTE) to avoid the repeated subquery.

Comment: select t1.country1, t2_1.amount as avg1, t1.country2, t2_2.amount
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.country, avg(amount) as amount
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.country
     ) t2_1
     on t1_2.country1 = t2_1.country join
     (select t2.country, avg(amount) as amount
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.country
     ) t2_2
     on t1.country2 = t2_2.country; I changed the query slightly because table 1 doesn't have country, it has country1 and country2. It does not seem to produce the result I need though. It is showing the average overall, not for when each combination occurs.